# How to readRDS from stdin?

Tags: r, macos, littler

I try to use the following command to read an RDS file. But it doesn't work. My OS is Mac OS X.

```
$ lr -e "readRDS(file('stdin'))" < /tmp/x.rds 
Error in readRDS(file("stdin")) : unknown input format
$ lr -p -e "readRDS('/dev/stdin')" < /tmp/x.rds 
Error in readRDS("/dev/stdin") : error reading from connection
```

But this works.

```
$ lr -p -e "readRDS('/tmp/x.rds')"
  x  y
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
```

Does anybody know how to readRDS from stdin? Thanks.

Comment: To my reading, the documentation for `help(readRDS)` does not suggest you can do this. I think the format requires `seek()` access which you cannot do a piped stream.

Comment: Which sentence it says this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (on linux, using littler 0.3.9 on R-devel) using '/dev/stdin' instead of 'stdin'; so try:

```r
lr -p -e "print(readRDS('/dev/stdin'))" < /tmp/x.rds
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `lr -p -e "print(readRDS(stdin())" < /tmp/x.rds` work? Don't currently have an easy way to test

Comment: `lr -p -e "readRDS('/dev/stdin')" < /tmp/x.rds` still gives me the same error. I am on Mac OS X.